# Disabled dates в Datepicker vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

Не могу разобраться как задать массив disabled дат только для одного календаря.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
   vuejsDatepicker
  },
  computed: {
   disabled: function () {
       dates: [
        new Date(2018, 11, 25),
        new Date(2018, 11, 28)
   ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.datepicker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker@1.5.3/dist/vuejs-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker" :disabled="disabled"></vuejs-datepicker>
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker"></vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так заработало

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
   vuejsDatepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      disabledDates: {
        dates: [
          new Date(2018, 10, 16),
          new Date(2018, 10, 17),
          new Date(2018, 10, 18)
        ]
      }
    };
  }
})
```

```css
.datepicker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker@1.5.3/dist/vuejs-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker" :disabled-dates="disabledDates"></vuejs-datepicker>
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker"></vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как написано у них в документации [ссылка](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#disabled-dates), ты должен сделать следующее:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
   vuejsDatepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      disabledDates: {
        dates: [
          new Date(2016, 9, 16),
          new Date(2016, 9, 17),
          new Date(2016, 9, 18)
        ]
      }
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker@1.5.3/dist/vuejs-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker" :disabled="disabledDates"></vuejs-datepicker>
  <vuejs-datepicker class="datepicker"></vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: Так не работает, я уже пробывал,календарь становится нерабочим.

Comment: @Mr.V так ты return не сделал в своем коде. у тебя туда undefined передается. Просто вставь мой код